# Setting up sale on Google Play with price below 0.99 USD

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

One of our apps (m-parking) has turned 2 years old a week ago and developers would like to reward our current users with a limited-time offer (1 month) of "Premium license" (in-app payment item) sale with 50% price discount.

The [In-app Billing Pricing help pages](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153485) say:

> You cannot set a price of “0” (free)

which leads one to believe that you can set it to 0.01, but the reality is different and is the same as for app pricing --> you can't put price lower than 0.99 USD (and equivalents in other currencies).

Proof: 
[image: screenshot from Google Play]

So, the problem is that we all (at least many of us) know **it is possible** because we bought apps/games which were priced at $0.49 and $0.25.

### The goal

Current "Premium license" item price is 8.89 SEK (1.35 USD) and we would like to set the price at 4.49 SEK (0.67 USD and equivalents) for one month.

Is that possible and how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for you as a developer to set a lower price on Google Play Store. The times you've seen cheaper prices is when Google has some special sale, but then it's up to Google to select the apps to put on sale.

Other app stores have other price limits, so you may be able to publish your apps on those. For example SlideMe have a lowest limit of $0.50, I think. But that doesn't really affect in-app purchases, so I don't think what you want is possible.

Another option for you may be to provide a passcode based solution to activate premium features. You can give those out for free for some time. I don't think it's allowed by Google to let users pay for things like that outside of the Play Store, since they would then lose their part of the profit.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It would be useful to have that (namely Google selecting apps for sale) documented somewhere.